# Записать в csv и положить в zip

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть cписок словарей. Мне необходимо сделать из этого csv-файл и положить в zip-архив. Делаю так:

```
 csv_file = StringIO()
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    csv_writer.writerow([key for key, value in data[0].items()])
    for row in data:
        row_list = [item.encode('cp1251') if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in row]
        csv_writer.writerow(row_list)

    zip_file = StringIO()
    zip_obj = ZipFile(zip_file, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zip_obj.writestr('export.csv', csv_file.getvalue())
    zip_obj.close()
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Скажите, оптимально ли это решение и как избавиться от этой ошибки ?

Полный `Traceback`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samojlov/myprojects/monitoring_gpr/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/samojlov/myprojects/monitoring_gpr/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/samojlov/myprojects/monitoring_gpr/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/samojlov/myprojects/monitoring_gpr/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/samojlov/myprojects/monitoring_gpr/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/samojlov/myprojects/monitoring_gpr/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/samojlov/myprojects/monitoring_gpr/app/views/monitoring.py", line 50, in export
    return export_handler.update(request)
  File "/home/samojlov/myprojects/monitoring_gpr/app/handlers/data_export_handler.py", line 31, in update
    zip_obj.writestr('export.csv', csv_file.getvalue())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1581, in writestr
    self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader(zip64))
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Comment: В Питоне 3, пишите строки, а не байты в csv (вы хотите: `abc`, а не `b'abc'` получить)¶ Приведите полный traceback, чтобы было ясно какой код выбрасывает ошибку¶ Слово "оптимально" требует указания конкретных критериев так как за исключением тривиальных случаев, вещь оптимальная в одной ситуации может являться вредной в другой¶ Если файлы такие большие что сжимать приходится, то можно `pandas` библиотекой воспользоваться: `df.to_csv('data.csv.xz', index=False, compression='xz')`, где `df` это аналог `pandas.DataFrame(data)`.

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать на примере как будет глядеть мой код в рабочем состоянии ?

Comment: создайте минимальный полный пример кода, который демонстрирует ошибку. Начните с нуля (если ошибку можно получить, не используя flask, zipfile или csv, то   уберите код их использующий). [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

```py
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from zipfile import ZIP_DEFLATED

data = [
    {'dict1_key1': 'dict1_val1', 'dict1_key2': 'dict1_val2'},
    {'dict2_key1': 'dict2_val1', 'dict2_key2': 'dict2_val2'}
]

csv_file = StringIO()
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
csv_writer.writerow([key for key, value in data[0].items()])
for row in data:
    row_list = [item.encode('cp1251') if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in row]
    csv_writer.writerow(row_list)

zip_obj = ZipFile("archive.zip", 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED)
zip_obj.writestr('export.csv', csv_file.getvalue())
zip_obj.close()
```

Создается archive.zip с файлом export.csv.
Содержание файла export.csv при этом получается таким:

```
dict1_key1;dict1_key2
dict1_key1;dict1_key2
dict2_key1;dict2_key2
```

Python version 2.7.11.

Comment: А где значения в файле ? Одни ключи...

Comment: Обратите внимание на следующую строку:
'csv_writer.writerow([key for key, value in data[0].items()])'
никто здесь с value и не работает.

Также и тут:
'item.encode('cp1251') if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in row'